# Plot Time Only in Matplotlib (Instead of DateTime)

Tags: python, matplotlib

My Dataframe is in this format

```
   Time    AvgDiff
07:00:00   7.750782
07:01:00   9.306567
07:02:00  13.225209
07:03:00  18.346431
07:04:00  10.049761
07:05:00  18.567049
07:06:00  -4.903014
07:07:00 -10.66217
```

I did the following to create a synthetic date, the date is not important as my AvgDiff is the average of all dates for the particular time value

```
my_day = datetime.date(2018, 1, 15)
x_dt = [ datetime.datetime.combine(my_day, t) for t in df['Time'] ]
x = x_dt
y1 = df['AvgDiff']


plt.bar(x,y1, label='AvgDiff BPS', width=0.001) #bar to plot
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.title('AvgDiff BPS')
plt.ylabel('BPS')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

This shows

[image]

It shows both the Date and Hours behind (in the X-Axis), However I need it to show just the Hours and Minutes.

I tried

```
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
df['Time'] = df['Time'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), FMT))
df['Time'] = df['Time'].map(lambda x: x.replace(day=date, month=month, year=year))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

But it produces the exact same chart, why is that so?

Answer (score 21):

Ok I managed to solve this as per below

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xformatter = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
plt.gcf().axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(xformatter)
```

This produces Hour:Minute

[image]

Comment: Where exactly does `mdates` come from?

Comment: It appears that `mdates` comes from `import matplotlib.dates as mdates`